# prolog: maximally repeated element in a list

Tags: prolog

Any ideas how to retrieve the maximally repeated element in a list.

i.e. something like below,

```
?- maxRepeated([1,2,7,3,6,1,2,2,3],M).
M = 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution sorts the list, granting elements to appear sequentially -- there's no need to maintain all elements, once they're not repeating later.

Your prolog interpreter must have the function `msort()`, which sorts a list maintaining duplicated entries.

```
maxRepeated([], []).
maxRepeated(L, E) :-
    msort(L, [H|T]),
    maxRepeated(T, H, H, 1, 0, E).

maxRepeated([], H, _, C1, C2, H) :- C1 >= C2.
maxRepeated([], _, X, C1, C2, X) :- C1 < C2.

maxRepeated([H|T], H, LastF, C1, C2, E) :-
    maxRepeated(T, H, LastF, C1 + 1, C2, E).

maxRepeated([X|T], H, LastF, C1, C2, E) :-
    (
        C1 > C2
        ->  maxRepeated(T, X, H, 1, C1, E)
        ;   maxRepeated(T, X, LastF, 1, C2, E)
    ).
```

The complexity is given by the sort used, usually `O(n log n)`, once, after the sort, the list is traversed only once, aggregating the elements and keeping track of the most frequent  one.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will accept this one as the answer since it is more general and elaborate than my solution.

Comment: Thank you, that's a pleasure to forget about some stuff while poking around with prolog programming. Your answer is very nice too, and it's even better if it's been made by yourself (: Regards!

Answer (score 4):

I like so much the relational Prolog power:

```
maxRepeated(L, M) :-
    sort(L, S),
    maplist(count(L), S, C),
    keysort(C, [_-M|_Ms]).
count(L, S, I-S) :-
    aggregate(count, member(S, L), C), I is -C.
```

test:

```
?- maxRepeated([1,2,7,3,6,1,2,2,3],M).
M = 2.
```

**edit** and now, still more compact!

```
maxRepeated(L, M) :-
    setof(I-E, C^(aggregate(count, member(E, L), C), I is -C), [_-M|_]).
```

Comment: nice answer! very neat one!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the max value that A<sub>i</sub> can take and if this A<sub>max</sub> is such that you can create an array as large as A<sub>max</sub> then there is a method by which you can find the most repeated element in **O(n)** time.

```
int A[max+1]; // set all elements to 0
int S[n]; // Set S
for (i=0;i<n;i++) A[ S[i] ]++;

int m=0, num; // num is the number to be found
for (i=1;i<=max;i++)
  if (A[i] > m)
  {
    m = A[i];
    num = i;
  }
print (num)
```

Comment: which version of prolog is this?

Comment: This isn't prolog. I've posted pseudo code just to tell you the algorithm. You can then use it in prolog in any way you want. :-)

Comment: version: swi-prolog XPCE 6.6.66

Comment: That's not what he meant @Zoran :p Don't count on getting copy-paste code :)

Comment: A professor once told, I' d teach you prolog more easily, if you didnt already know procedural programming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty answer. I constrained the problem to a set of allowed elements. Works but needs elaboration.

```
maxRepeated([],_,Current,_,Current).
maxRepeated([H|T],L,Current,MaxCount,X) :-
    (
         count(L,H,N),
         N > MaxCount,
     maxRepeated(T,L,H,N,X) 
    )
    ;
    maxRepeated(T,L,Current,MaxCount,X).

count([],X,0).
count([X|T],X,Y):- count(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z.
count([X1|T],X,Z):- X1\=X,count(T,X,Z).
```