# How I get most repetitive element of this? (Prolog - Logic Paradigm)

Tags: prolog

In predicate "sample", the first element is your id and the others, are the result of the sample.

```
sample(1,04,05,30,33,41,52).
sample(2,05,37,39,41,43,49).
sample(3,05,11,29,30,36,47).
sample(4,01,05,06,27,42,59).
```

I need to get the most repeated value of sample... In this case is the "05" and I don't have idea how I do this. How I can do this?

Comment: Are your id's consecutive? Is it possible that one number is missing?

Comment: Yes, is consecutive.

Comment: `sample(Id, [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D5])` would be a much better representation.

Answer (score 0):

If the id's are consecutive and start with 1, then this is a possible structure for a solution:

I would first change the format of the represented samples:

```
:- dynamic([sample/2,sample/7]). 
represent_samples:-
     retract(sample(I,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6)),
     assert(sample(I,[S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6])),
     fail.

represent_samples.
```

The first line `:- dynamic([sample/2,sample/7]).` declares the predicates `sample/2` and `sample/7` to be dynamic predicates; that means that clauses of them can be added and retracted from your knowledge base. The `retract` line retracts a `sample/7` fact from the knowlege, while the next line starting with `assert` adds it `sample/2` representation. The line `fail` ensures that this is done as long as there are `sample/7` facts in the knowledge base and the single `represent_samples.` fact guarantees that your predicate `represent_samples/0` succeeds.

You can check the effect of this predicate by the following sequence of queries:

```
  ?- listing([sample/2,sample/7]).
  ?- represent_samples.
  ?- listing([sample/2,sample/7]).
```

After re-representing the samples one can go through them (guided by the id).

```
most_rep(N):-
    most_rep(1,[],N).

most_rep(I,Acc,N):-
    sample(I,L),
    append(L,Acc,NewAcc),
    I1 is I+1,
    most_rep(I1,NewAcc,N).

most_rep(_I,Acc,N):-
    choose_most_freq(Acc,N).
```

Now we only have to write the predicate `choose_most_freq/2` that identifies the most frequent element in a list.

For this problem you could use the solution posted on [prolog: maximally repeated element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673623/prolog-maximally-repeated-element-in-a-list/13674216#13674216)

```
choose_most_freq(L, M) :-
    setof(I-E, C^(aggregate(count, member(E, L), C), I is -C), [_-M|_]).
```

Comment: the first stretch, don't work. By the way, I've never used these commands. Sorry, I forgot to write in english.

Comment: I have commented my `represent_samples/0` predicate, maybe that helps.